# Spring Boot - Unable to set up Cucumber with selenium

Tags: java, spring, selenium, spring-boot

In my Spring boot application I want to set up a cucumber test with selenium. However, when I run the tests, the response is an empty page, and it appears the connection is refused. My code is as follows. What I'm doing wrong?

CucumberTest.java

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/cucumber/features")
public class CucumberTest {

}
```

DashboardLoginStep.java

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, loader = 
                SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@IntegrationTest
@WebAppConfiguration
public class DashboardLoginStep {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
    }

    @Given("^the politician is in the login page$")
    public void isInLoginPage() {
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        driver.get("http://localhost:8090/");
        driver.navigate().to("http://localhost:8090/");
        System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
        System.out.println("The politician is in the login page");
    }

    @Then("^introduces his credentials, \"(.+)\" and \"(.+)\" into the login 
    form$")
    public void insertCredentials(String mail, String psw) {
        System.out.println("Introduces his credentials");
    }

    @When("^he pushes the \"Log in\" button$")
    public void pushLogIn() {
        System.out.println("He pushes the login button");
    }

    @And("^he gets redirected to the dashboard view$")
    public void isInDashboard() {
        System.out.println("He gets redirected to the dashboard view");
    }
}
```

The prints appear succesfully on the console, meaning that the cucumber step is being executed, but the selenium part returns an empty page and the connection is aborted.

Thank you.

Comment: try put breakpoints on the code you want to check whether it is executed or not, if you define driver.get, you don't need driver.navigate.to, and remove get page source at the start of the isInLoginPage

Comment: probably you are missing `glue` in your runner class which should be like : `@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/cucumber/features" glue="yourPackageName.DashboardLoginStep ")`